# When to use Payment method facade

Tags: magento2, payment, payment-gateway

I am working custom payment method in Magento 2. I referred Magento documentation http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/base-integration/payment-option-config.html where 
they mentioned using **Payment method facade**.

But I reviewed core model `module-authorizenet` where they have not used Payment method facade

They used "`Magento\Authorizenet\Model\Directpost`" instead of Payment method facade.

I am bit confused with when to use Payment method facade.

So when to use Payment method facade?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 payment gateway facade, refers to the front side or display side of the payment gateway, it includes The frontend attributes, the method, observer, assign data fields, you can find in detail in here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/base-integration/facade-configuration.html

Comment: I already know this link

Comment: @Pandurang Babar is asking for an explanation for the Payment method facade used in Magento 2. A vague explanation and a link to an article that is not suitable for a beginner are not helping at all.